# Querying data from DPBEDIA Using SPARQL and Service in GraphDB

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am using the free version of GraphDB and want to select some data from DBpedia.

The following is what I tried:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

Select ?about 
WHERE {
    dbr:Eiffel_Tower a ?o .
    SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
        dbr:Eiffel_Tower dbo:abstract ?about .
     }
    FILTER (LANG(?about) = "de")
}
```

However, I get no results.

If I run the query on http://factforge.net/ like:

```
Select ?about
Where {
    dbr:Eiffel_Tower dbo:abstract ?about .
}
```

or even like:

```
Select ?about 
WHERE {
    dbr:Eiffel_Tower a ?stuff .
    SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
        dbr:Eiffel_Tower dbo:abstract ?about .
     }
    FILTER (LANG(?about) = "de")
}
```

I get what I want (I get 9 times the Germany about. Well, actually not quite, I want it only once.why?).

So my question is, why isn't it working and how can I make it work?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `dbr:Eiffel_Tower a ?o .
    SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> {` - is evaluated as join between the first triple pattern matching your local dataset and the remote dataset. It's likely that your local dataset doesn't contain data matching the first triple pattern, right? Thus, the join would indeed be empty. If not, which DBpedia data did you load? It should be the instance_types_en dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What DBpedia-linked data (i.e., anything describing `dbr:Eiffel_Tower`) have you loaded into your local GraphDB instance? I'm betting on "none."

I think if you comment (or remove) the `dbr:Eiffel_Tower a ?o .` line, you'll get results.

You should also move the `FILTER` into the subquery, because right now you're pulling much more data from DBpedia than you need or want.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?about 
WHERE
  {
  #  dbr:Eiffel_Tower a ?o .
     SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql>
       {
         dbr:Eiffel_Tower dbo:abstract ?about .
         FILTER (LANG(?about) = "de")
       }
  }
```